# Can biblatex automatically lowercase?

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

In the standard styles, bibtex automatically lowercases the titles of bibliography entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{inproceedings-minimal}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Auto-lowercasing in bibtex]

When using biblatex, however, this somewhat dubious behaviour is not retained:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{xampl}
\begin{document}
\nocite{inproceedings-minimal}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Case preserving in biblatex]

(I'm still using biblatex v1.7, which probably makes a difference, but I can't see anything in the latest release that indicates this has changed.)

Is there any way to have biblatex behave like the standard bibtex styles?

While I understand the philosophy of preserving the case of the entry (just do it right the first time!), in my case I've been building a bibliography for some ten years now and just this once would like to indeed lowercase my entries. I'm normalising my bibliography by hand as we speak, but it's probably a good idea to archive this here in case other people have the same issue.

Comment: Hell. I did search before asking! Thanks for the pointers.